# How do I get this simple array to work? (Beginner level Python)

Tags: python

I'm terribly sorry I have to ask such a ridiculously simple question, but I've been looking for the answer for awhile now, I feel like an idiot, but I cannot seem to get this to work.

I simply want to create an array with 10 variables, each defined by the user, and then have the option to add them all together. I can't even get the first parts correctly though. Here is my code so far:

```
def makeArray():
    a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    a[0] = input("Please input 1st number: \n")
    a[1] = input("Please input 2nd number: \n")
    a[2] = input("Please input 3rd number: \n")
    a[3] = input("Please input 4th number: \n")
    a[4] = input("Please input 5th number: \n")
    a[5] = input("Please input 6th number: \n")
    a[6] = input("Please input 7th number: \n")
    a[7] = input("Please input 8th number: \n")
    a[8] = input("Please input 9th number: \n")
    a[9] = input("Please input 10th number: \n")
def main():
    makeArray()
    print(a[2])
main()
```

Whenever I run it though after entering the 10 values I get "Global name 'a' is not defined." can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the array, as such:

```
def makeArray():
    a = []
    for x in xrange(10):
        a.append(input("Please input the %d number: " % x))
    return a

def main():
    my_array = makeArray()
    print(my_array[2])
main()
```

Comment: The OP's original method was not idiomatic and was the long way of doing it, but it was syntactically correct.  All that was missing before was the `return` statement and the variable assignment in the `main` function.  I just wanted to point this out so that the OP knows exactly what they did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 a's. One who's scope is in makeArray and the other that is in main.

in main:

```
a = list ()
makeArray (a)
```

Should get things working nicely. (Take out the initialization in makeArray.) Note that all of the elements of the array in your program will be strings.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must be misunderstanding.. I replaced the code in main with yours and it still doesn't work "makeArray() takes no arguments (1 given)" and how can I make the array values integers?

Comment: Ah, yes. Of course you need to add a as a paremeter in makeArray (a).

Answer (score 1):

This is a smaller version of your code with the same error:

```
def makeList():
    a=[0,1,2]

def main():
    makeList()
    print a[1]

main()
```

You can fix it like this:

```
def makeList():
    a=[0,1,2]
    return a

def main():
    a=makeList()
    print a[1]

main()
```

BTW -- 'arrays' are called 'lists' in Python, unless you are specifically using the array module or numpy to create arrays...

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you

Edit: How do I make each value based off input though?